# Ordering a hash in descending order in Ruby doesn't work

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash that contains commit id (key) and a number (value). In the following how I added the value to the hash:

```
@allCommits[commit] = count
```

The following is an example for commit ids and their values:

```
Key: 42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21
Value: 3
Key: a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571
Value: 1
Key: 4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c
Value: 1
Key: 469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e
Value: 4
Key: 66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a
Value: 1
Key: ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913
Value: 2
```

Then, before printing I want to order the hash in descending order based on value. So, I did

```
@allCommits.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
```

But it did't work, it gave me the order as I insert them in hash.

I also, tried

```
Hash[@allCommits.sort_by{|k, v| v}.reverse]
```

But nothing.

I can't see the problem here, any help?

Comment: It's better to replace your description of key/value pair to a real `Hash` literal example. Currently it's unclear, e.g, are the values integers or strings?

Comment: The example you see is exactly what I get when I print out the hash.

Comment: Can not reproduce: `{'42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21':3,'a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571':1,'4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c':1,'469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e':4,'66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a':1,'ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913':2}.sort_by{|_,v|v}.reverse#=>[[:"469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e", 4],
 [:"42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21", 3],
 [:ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913, 2],
 [:"4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c", 1],
 [:a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571, 1],
 …`

Comment: Both `1` and `'1'` prints out `1`, which one is it? Especially since `10 > 2` while `'10' < '2'`. Learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Values are integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be working for me:

Input:

```
@all_commits = {
  '42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21' => 3,
  'a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571' => 1,
  '4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c' => 1,
  '469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e' => 4,
  '66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a' => 1,
  'ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913' => 2
}

puts "Sorted"
@all_commits.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse.each{|x| p x}
puts
puts "Unsorted"
@all_commits.each{|x| p x}
```

Output:

```
Sorted
["469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e", 4]
["42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21", 3]
["ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913", 2]
["4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c", 1]
["a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571", 1]
["66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a", 1]

Unsorted
["42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21", 3]
["a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571", 1]
["4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c", 1]
["469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e", 4]
["66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a", 1]
["ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913", 2]
```

My guess is that you perform `sort_by` but do not capture the results. In ruby, many methods return **new** objects, and do not update the original hash. So if you have a hash, then call `sort_by` on it, then on a separate line try to print the hash again, you'll see the original hash because it wasn't updated. Instead you have to use the return value of the `sort_by` call.

Comment: What do you mean by capturing the result?

Comment: Updated my answer a bit more. Basically, if you don't use the return value of a `sort_by` or a `reverse` all its hard work disappears, and you're back to the hash you started with.

Comment: Okay I see. it works now if I print it. But how if I want to use it later?

Comment: It sounds like you already figured it out. But, for completeness, the answer to your "use it later" question is to simply store the result in a variable: `sorted = hash.sort.reverse`

Answer (score 0):

I make this test and seems that your code work:

```
commits = {"42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21" => 3,
"a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571" => 1,
"4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c" => 1, 
"469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e" => 4, 
"66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a" => 1, 
"ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913" => 2}

puts commits.sort_by {|k,v| v}.reverse
```

Output:

```
469a15d2ecea8671a3f3c77813011163e2605d9e
4
42ac06787b8db8a6a299aa65482072f238dffc21 
3
ee9b9bac044c8306c81c7b3a3aa0632a7835e913 
2
4ab0aab2e5fe9d650ce1fb96c48587783c7e296c
1
a2658427039df49687d5ea590d8a0053631a2571
1
66558be4e7ddd5e9d9db3d512c859410d275c97a
1
```